# Delete a field in a Firestore doc from a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

how can I delete a field in a document from a cloud firestore function ?

I'm using transactions, so I tried this approach :

```
    const { FieldValue } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
    ...   
    ..
    transaction.update(docRef, { fieldToRemove: FieldValue.delete() });
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
Transaction failure: Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Document. Couldn't serialize object of type "DeleteTransform". Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the 'new' operator).
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to use `FieldValue.delete()` as per [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields), but need to import it from 'firebase-admin' instead:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
transaction.update(docRef, { fieldToRemove: FieldValue.delete() });
```